# Find all functions $ f(x^2+y^2) + f(xf(y) + f(x)f(y)) = (f(x+y))^2. $

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$ f(x^2+y^2) + f(xf(y) + f(x)f(y)) = (f(x+y))^2. $

My attempt:

Plugging in  $x=y=0$ we get  $f(0) + f(f(0)^2) = f(0)^2. $
Setting $x:=y$  and  $y:=x$ gets us  $f(xf(y)+f(x)f(y)) = f(yf(x)+f(x)f(y)).$
Setting $f(0)=a$ and plugging in $x=0$ and $ y=a $, we get $f(a^2) + f(af(a)) = f(a)^2. $
$x=a$ and $ y=0 $ gives us $ f(a^2) + f(a^2+af(a)) = f(a)^2.$
How can I continue?

Comment: The $x=y=0$ is a good first step. My next step would be to set $y=-x$.

Comment: @RedFive I did that but I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: @Aig it’s from Romanian National Olympiad shortlist 2023

Comment: @Aig do you an idea on how to solve it?